# How to capture “Enter key” in combobox using WIN32 API (C/C++)?

Tags: api, winapi, combobox, key, enter

I want catch event when user press Enter in combobox. How to catch you. For Example:
I type " Nguyen Phong Sac" in my combobox. After pressing Enter key, there is a message is displayed: " Nguyen Phong Sac".
Thanks yours helps,

Comment: Is it native win32 api(not .net nor mfc)? You need to add WM_KEYDOWN to your message proc.

Comment: I want to catch Enter key in combobox

Comment: Can you give me an example?

Comment: @Xearinox Because writing with .Net(WPF/Winforms)/MFC for UI is way much faster and easier than using Win32 API directly. It isn't about if I understand the power of WIN32 API, it is about using Claymore for cutting butters. For example, the client for a driver I wrote used C++ for kernel communication and WPF for UI.

Comment: I don't think so. Win32 API faster than .Net framework. But it is harder to build a win32 app

Comment: Yes it is faster indeed, the real question is do you need it for your program(for example a calculator)? If you want the fastest, go for win32 asm.

Comment: Học WinAPI thì hay mà riết thì cũng chán àh

Answer (score 9):

I still want to know what kind of program are you writing, but I will give you an example as you asked:

```
//Tested with Windows 7 x64, VS2012
//When Creating:
hWndComboBox = CreateWindow(WC_COMBOBOX, TEXT(""), 
               CBS_DROPDOWN | CBS_HASSTRINGS | WS_CHILD | WS_OVERLAPPED | WS_VISIBLE,
               xpos, ypos, nwidth, nheight, hwndParent, NULL, HINST_THISCOMPONENT,
               NULL);

hWndEditBox = CreateWindow(WC_EDIT, TEXT(""), 
              CBS_DROPDOWN | CBS_HASSTRINGS | WS_CHILD | WS_OVERLAPPED | WS_VISIBLE,
              xpos, ypos-30, nwidth, 30, hwndParent, NULL, HINST_THISCOMPONENT,
              NULL);

//Get hwnd of edit control in combobox created earlier.
HWND hwndEdit = GetWindow(hWndComboBox, GW_CHILD);
//Use SetWindowLong to create subclass, lpfnEditWndProc is original proc
lpfnEditWndProc = (WNDPROC) SetWindowLong(hwndEdit, GWL_WNDPROC, (DWORD) SubClassProc); 


//In Subclass Proc
LRESULT CALLBACK SubClassProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) 
{ 
   switch (msg) 
   { 
    case WM_KEYDOWN: 
        switch (wParam) 
        {  
            case VK_RETURN: 
                                    //Get Text&Set Text
                LPTSTR buffer = new TCHAR[255];
                GetWindowText(hwnd, buffer, 255);
                SetWindowText(hWndEditBox, buffer);
            break;
        } 
        break; 

  } 

  return CallWindowProc(lpfnEditWndProc, hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know that is 2 late, but you can use WndProc

```
        protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
        {
              if (m.Msg == 0x100 && (int)m.WParam == 13){
                    //Enter pressed
              }

              base.WndProc (ref m);
        }
```

Comment: this is c# and not c++

Answer (score 0):

You can also achieve this in WTL

```
#define YOUR_WM_ENTER WM_USER + 2

class CCommandBarEdit : public CWindowImpl<CCommandBarEdit, CEdit, CControlWinTraits>
{
    typedef CWindowImpl<CCommandBarEdit, CEdit, CControlWinTraits> baseClass;

public:
    HWND hwndMain;

    DECLARE_WND_SUPERCLASS(_T("YOUR_COMMANDBAREDIT"), _T("EDIT"));

    BEGIN_MSG_MAP(CCommandBarEdit)
        MESSAGE_HANDLER(WM_CHAR, OnKeyDown)
        DEFAULT_REFLECTION_HANDLER()
    END_MSG_MAP()

private:
    LRESULT OnKeyDown(UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam, BOOL& bHandled)
    {
        if (wParam == VK_RETURN && GetFocus() == m_hWnd)
        {
            ::SendMessage(hwndMain,  YOUR_WM_ENTER,0,0);
        }
        else
        {
            bHandled = FALSE;
        }

        return 0;
    }
};
```

Where you keep the edit container, m_Combo is your combobox

```
CCommandBarEdit m_cmdTextBox;

HWND hWndEdit = ::GetWindow(m_Combo.m_hWnd, GW_CHILD);
    if (hWndEdit)
        m_cmdTextBox.SubclassWindow(hWndEdit);
```

Where you respond to the message

```
MESSAGE_HANDLER(YOUR_WM_ENTER, OnCommandEnter)
LRESULT CMainFrame::OnCommandEnter(UINT /*uMsg*/, WPARAM /*wParam*/, LPARAM /*lParam*/, BOOL& /*bHandled*/)
```